# Proof of $\sum_{n=-k}^{k}e^{2\pi i nx}=\frac{sin(2k+1)\pi x}{\sin\pi x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

As the question in the title. I want to prove $$\sum_{n=-k}^{k}e^{2\pi i nx}=\frac{sin(2k+1)\pi x}{\sin\pi x}.$$

Any help would appreciated.

Thank so much.

Comment: It's the sum of a geometric progression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=-k}^ke^{2\pi inx}=e^{-2k\pi ix}+e^{(2(1-k)\pi ix)}+e^{(2(2-k)\pi ix)}...$$
$$\sum_{n=-k}^ke^{2\pi inx}=e^{-2k\pi ix}+e^{(-2k\pi ix)+2\pi ix}+e^{(-2k\pi ix)+4\pi ix}...$$

This is a geometric series with common ratio $e^{2\pi ix}$

To prove the identity, you just need to find the sum of this series using the formula for a geometric series.  $$\frac{U_1(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$

You know that $U_1=e^{-2k\pi ix}$, so this should lead you to your answer.

Comment: Confirmed. Thank you.